# SQL error: 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am running a SQL script but getting an error:

> 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query
>   batch

Here's my code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'myproc') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]

AS
BEGIN
    select * from mytable
END
GO
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 56):

Run your statement in the following form:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'myproc') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
  DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
GO
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
AS
BEGIN
    select * from mytable
END
GO
```

Note the `GO` batch separator after `DROP PROCEDURE`

Comment: Note also that if GO is followed by a semicolon, the error message will persist. (SQLSrv apparently interprets the semicolon as an empty statement prior to CREATE). This one stumped me for a while.

Comment: @xr280xr You are right, the VS is divide the script to batches according to GO stmt, but semicolon is not a part of GO

Comment: Can we add to this that the 'Go' statement must be on a line by itself?

Comment: The GO keyword is the secret sauce.  Run your script above without GO and you will encounter the same error.

Answer (score 33):

The error message you are getting is correct. You can terminate the batch (and start another) with the GO keyword.

Place GO right before your Create procedure statement. The GO statement must be on a line by itself.

Comment: 'The GO statement must be on a line by itself.'  Very important part to get this to work.

Answer (score 13):

Often I wish to do the reverse of what you are asking.  For example if the user has customized a procedure, and I don't want to lose their changes, yet I want to apply a uniform update script for all my clients, I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
if not exists ( select * from sys.objects 
            where name='myProc' and objectproperty(object_id,'IsProcedure')=1 )
create proc myProc 
as begin
  -- proc stmts here
end
go
```

This logic would allow me to create something only if it DOESN'T exist, but to my great frustration, SQL Server prevents this too.

I get around this problem easily enough as follows:

```
if not exists ( select * from sys.objects 
            where name='myProc' and objectproperty(object_id,'IsProcedure')=1 )
exec('create proc myProc 
as begin
  -- proc stmts here
  declare @object int = 0
end')
go
```

By passing the create proc command as a string and placing it in an exec statement we circumvent the stupid rule that prevents one from doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

My problem went away after I added the following statements:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

Comment: The fix is not neccasarily the ansi_null = on and quoted_identifier = on, but rather the go that seperates the scripts to execute

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try this to create stored procedure in another database rather than create it in current context.

```
set @myScript = 'exec '+ QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '..sp_executesql N''create PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
AS
BEGIN
    select * from mytable
END'''
execute(@myScript)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @rn INT = 1, @dbname varchar(MAX) = '';

DECLARE @myScript varchar(MAX) = '';
WHILE @DBName IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN


 SET @DBName = (SELECT name FROM (SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn 
        FROM sys.databases WHERE name  IN ('RBAC','sakila')) t WHERE rn = @rn);
    
set @myScript = 'exec '+ QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '..sp_executesql N''Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
AS
BEGIN
    select  765
END'''
execute(@myScript)
SET @rn = @rn + 1;
END;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain **why** and **how** it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the 'GO' key at the beginning of the procedure query.