# T-SQL install / upgrade script as a transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I'm trying to write a single T-SQL script which will upgrade a system which is currently in deployment. The script will contain a mixture of:

- New tables
- New columns on existing tables
- New functions
- New stored procedures
- Changes to stored procedures
- New views
- etc.

As it's a reasonably large upgrade I want the script to rollback if a single part of it fails.  I have an outline of my attempted code below:

```
DECLARE @upgrade NVARCHAR(32);
SELECT @upgrade = 'my upgrade';

BEGIN TRANSACTION @upgrade
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Starting';
    BEGIN TRY
        CREATE TABLE x ( --blah...
        );

        ALTER TABLE y --blah...
        );

        CREATE PROCEDURE z AS BEGIN ( --blah...
        END
        GO  --> this is causing trouble!

        CREATE FUNCTION a (  --blah...

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH    
        PRINT 'Error with transaction. Code: ' + @@ERROR + '; Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @upgrade;
        PRINT 'Rollback complete';
        RETURN;
    END TRY
END
PRINT 'Upgrade successful';
COMMIT TRANSACTION @upgrade;
GO
```

*Note - I know some of the syntax is not perfect - I'm having to re-key the code*

It seems as though I can't put Stored Procedures into a transaction block.  Is there a reason for this?  Is it because of the use of the word `GO`? If so, how can I put SPs into a transaction block?  What are the limitations as to what can go into a transaction block?  Or, what would be a better alternative to what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks

Comment: How many times do you plan to do this?

Comment: Only the one upgrade...

Comment: you should be able to wrap all of your DDL statements in one large transaction, although as mentioned you'll have to remove any `GO` statements. I would also advise backing up your database before you start - that way you'll have the option of the uber rollback statement, `RESTORE DATABASE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the GO and create your procedure by using dynamic sql or it will fail.

```
EXEC ('create procedure z 
  as
  begin
    print "hello world"
  end')
```

GO is not a SQL keyword, it is a batch separator. So it cannot be included into a transaction.

Please refer to those topics for further information :

[sql error:'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051006/sql-errorcreate-alter-procedure-must-be-the-first-statement-in-a-query-batch)

[Using "GO" within a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971177/using-go-within-a-transaction)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: I have tried removed the `GO`, however I then get syntax errors on the next `BEGIN` block, which result in a huge number of other syntax errors chained along to the end of the script!

Comment: See my edit, create a procedure needs to be the first statement if not embedded in dynamic sql

Comment: Will this allow multiple `EXEC` statments?

Comment: Yes you can use multiple EXEC into your transaction

Answer (score 3):

As Thomas Haratyk said in his answer, your issue was the "go". However, you can have as many batches in a transaction as you want. It's the try/catch that doesn't like this. Here's a simple proof-of-concept:

```
begin tran
go
select 1
go
select 2
go
rollback

begin try
    select 1
    go
    select 2
    go
end try
begin catch
    select 1
end catch
```