# Executing Entire .sql file on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute an entire file of SQL commands on SQL Server from a vb.net app. The issue is that if the SQL file contains any `CREATE PROCEDURE` commands, I get the following error:

> A critical error has occurred. 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the
>   first statement in a query batch. Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'PROC'

```
Dim sql = sqlFile.ReadToEnd()

Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SiteSqlServer").ToString), cmd As New SqlCommand
With cmd
    .Connection = conn
    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    .CommandText = sql
    .CommandTimeout = 300    
End With

conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery  
conn.Close()
```

How can I execute sql files over a `SqlConnection` containing `CREATE PROCEDURE` commands?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql error:'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051006/sql-errorcreate-alter-procedure-must-be-the-first-statement-in-a-query-batch)

Comment: make sure you have a batch separator `GO` between your Sql Statements.

Comment: Seperating commands with "GO" results in the following error:

A critical error has occurred. Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Comment: @M.Ali: that would work if you'd execute the script in SQL Server **Management Studio** - but from a .NET application, the `GO` won't help ....

Comment: hmm true @marc_s , is there any ANSI batch separator? I know `GO` is SSMS specific.

Comment: @M.Ali: no, not really. What I usually did was having a `.sql` with the `GO` in them to use in SSMS, and if I wanted to execute this `.sql` from C#, I need to split it up on the `GO` separators and execute each fragment separately against SQL Server

Comment: @marc_s, I second that, you should give this as answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that each `CREATE PROCEDURE` needs to be the first statement in a batch (as the error message clearly says).

If you'd be executing your `.sql` in SQL Server Management Studio, you could use `GO` as separators:

```
....
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomethingOrAnother......
```

but this `GO` is a SSMS-specific separator - not a general SQL statement.

There's really no "magic" way to execute a complete `.sql` script file against SQL Server from VB.NET - what I usually do are these steps:

- read in the whole `.sql` file into a string
- split the string containing the whole script into separate sub-strings on the `GO` separator
- execute each fragment that results from this splitting up separately, against SQL Server

That way, any `CREATE PROCEDURE ....` will be the first statement in a separate batch, and then your script should work just fine from VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave the `GO` separator in your script, but you should execute the script using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` objects that you can find in the

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies`  (or the appropriate dir for your version)

```
Dim cmd = File.ReadAllText("d:\temp\create.sql")
Using con = new SqlConnection("....")
    Dim svrConnection = new ServerConnection(con)
    Dim server = new Server(svrConnection)
    Dim col = new StringCollection()
    col.Add(cmd)
    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(col)
End Using
```

You need to have a reference (and imports) to the following assemblies

- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc