# "Unable to parse query text" error in Execute SQL task of SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms

I am working on a SSIS package. I needed a SQL query to be executed as a part of it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = Object_id(N'[dbo].[ProcCalls]') 
                 AND type IN (N'U')) 
BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProcCalls]
    (
         [ProcedureName] VARCHAR(100), 
         [ProcedureCall] VARCHAR(MAX), 
         [PodName] VARCHAR(50), 
         [AccountName] VARCHAR(50), 
         [OrganizationID] VARCHAR(50), 
         [CenterID] VARCHAR(50)
    ) 
END 
GO

TRUNCATE TABLE [ProcCalls]
```

I tried using both direct input and file connection input but both the times build query tab fails and I get this error:

> Unable to parse query text

Also upon execution, the package fails

PS: [stackoverflow.com/a/11128418](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11128418) This answer worked for me. I did put queries not starting with CREATE/ALTER in Exec() and the package executed successfully.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can always drop and create the table. `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[ProcCalls]; CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProcCalls] ()` It's a little simpler than your current code.

Comment: @qxg that depends on his SQL server version

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2016. @qxg Drop table construct is not allowed in SS 2016

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 states _IF EXISTS
Applies to: SQL Server ( SQL Server 2016 (13.x) through current version)._

Comment: Show us your result set - It looks like your trying to insert it into a variable based on your comments to keith harris

Comment: @Thomas Yeah. There was a redundant variable and I removed it to solve the problem. Anyway package has no errors now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "GO" and replace it with a semi-colon ";"

Comment: Tried it. But exact same problem remains. I found following error in output log "Error: 0xC002F210 at Create Stage table to Populate from File, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT        *
                   ..." failed with the following error: "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4) "

Comment: Are you using full resultset? Show us the ssis package setup from your execute task

Comment: I am using result set as none. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11128418
This answer worked for me.